# C# Permission to save file

Tags: c#

I have a C# Application that I've wrote. Everything works 100% besides one method. If UAC is turned on I can not save a file, not even the Settings.config. I tried using a manifest file, with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void UpdateVersionText()
 {
     var wc = new WebClient();
     var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
     var list = utf8.GetString(wc.DownloadData("https://www.agentsarea.co.uk/photolibrary/photos/data/version.txt"));
     wc.Dispose();
     Properties.Settings.Default.version = list.Trim();
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide the exception stacktrace to review?

Comment: There's no exception. Everything compiles and runs on a machine without UAC on. On a fresh install of Vista or WIn7 with UAC on the settings never save.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to downvote this question.  It's a very valid question.  Let he who has never attempted to save files to the \Program files\ directory cast the first downvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save the file to a better place.  You are probably saving to the current directory, which is in /Program files/, which a normal user should not write to.  Try saving to %appdata% (each Windows user has their own directory) or to %allusersprofile% (all users share the same directory).

You get either path by calling the following:

AppData for the current user:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

All users profile directory:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT! That was 1 of my problems, trying to save to the Program Files directory. My other problem was that of stupidity. I was never actually calling my save method. I feel so terribly stupid.

Comment: @Dremation: LOL, that will avert exceptions, though :-).  We've all been there, so don't feel stupid.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other comments, you should consider writing settings to [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to save it to in the file system? If you are trying inside Program Files you will get shut down by UAC. Try AppData or the My Documents areas and you should have more luck.

Comment: Initially I was trying to save to Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles) + "\\PPPL\\Data\\version.txt" But that failed so I tried saving to App Settings file.

Comment: @Dremation: CommonProgramFiles also requires elevation...  Stop trying to save it where windows wants to protect executables... You should be ok when you try user-accessible paths

Comment: I tried saving to C:\Users\Dremation\AppData\Roaming\PPPL\Data  with no luck. The Solution file contains 2 projects. 1 saves data to a sqlite db with no problem in the same directory. But the second application fails to save.

Comment: @Dremation: in that case you should get an exception.  See what kind of exception it is when you try to save.  Also make sure you are calling Environment.GetFolderPath() to get the directory name, and not hardcoding, as the name structure changes depending on several factors, so it's not portable from computer to computer.